# Upload files synchronously with RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava. I am receiving a Flowable object from the file API service.

I was able to upload a single file, but I want to upload as many files as the user chose.

I could use `.zip` and get the a list of the results, but I want to use a ProgressDialog which will be updated for each uploaded file.

Is there any possible way to get onNext() and onCompleted() callbacks for each uploaded file?

this is how I upload a single file:

```
final SelectablePhoto photo = currentProduct.getSelectablePhotos().get(i);
                Log.d("Uploading", "createFlowableSource:" + photo.getPhotoModel().getPath());
                if (photo.getPhotoModel().getPath() != null) {
                    Config config = new Config(FILE_STACK_API_KEY);

                    Client client = new Client(config);
                    String path = photo.getPhotoModel().getPath();

                    client.uploadAsync(path, true)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(fileLinkProgress -> {
                                if (fileLinkProgress.getData() != null) {
                                    //file has been uploaded
                                    String pathIn = fileLinkProgress.getData().imageTransform().url();
                                    photo.getPhotoModel().setPath(pathIn);
                                }
                            }, throwable -> {
                                Log.d("error upload", "error uploading file: " + throwable);
                                uploadDialog.dismiss();
                            });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `merge` operator. See: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: consider posting some code as an example. remember that links can change, be moved, be removed, etc.